# Bluetooth off when I first boot

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

Every time I start my Ubuntu 16.04.1 laptop, Bluetooth is **off** by default.

This is difficult because I can't use my Bluetooth keyboard to login and I have to open my laptop and use the built in keyboard.

How can I make Bluetooth turn **on** by default when I boot the machine?

It used to be on by default, and the only thing that's changed is I have installed the latest updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your `/etc/rc.local` file with `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local` :

`rfkill unblock bluetooth`

Then reboot and it should work again

Comment: This fixed the problem. Any idea what cause it? Did something change in a recent update?

Comment: No idea, I've switched to Arch so I can't tell you if it changed recently. Maybe that's the default conf